# Can't make assertions because exceptions are crashing my test in Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I want to test the response when I try to send invalid data to the API.

```
/** @test */
public function request_schedule_with_invalid_bdate()
{
    $response = $this->json('GET', '/api/schedule', [
      'bdate' => 'thisaintadate',
    ]);

    $response->assertStatus(422);
}
```

According to the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation) it should return a 422

> If the validation rules pass, your code will keep executing normally; however, if validation fails, an exception will be thrown and the proper error response will automatically be sent back to the user. In the case of a traditional HTTP request, a redirect response will be generated, while a JSON response will be sent for AJAX requests.

Also,

> When using the validate method during an AJAX request, Laravel ... generates a JSON response containing all of the validation errors. This JSON response will be sent with a 422 HTTP status code.

It sounds like Laravel should automatically handle the exception thrown and proceed with sending the response.

However, running this in PHPUnit would just cause an error.

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Feature\ScheduleTest::request_schedule_with_invalid_bdate
Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException: The given data was invalid.
```

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683592/phpunit-assert-that-an-exception-was-thrown) but using `$this->expectException(...);` will make the test pass but not run my assertions. If I assert the status to be something else other than 422, it will still pass.

My controller has this:

```
public function show(Request $request) 
{
  $attributes = $request->validate([
    'bdate' => 'required|date'
  ]);

  return ['data' => "It's valid."]
}
```

Here is my ExceptionHandler class (as requested by Martin H.) This is just what's out of the box. I haven't touched this class yet.

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler;

class Handler extends ExceptionHandler
{
    /**
     * A list of the exception types that are not reported.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontReport = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * A list of the inputs that are never flashed for validation exceptions.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $dontFlash = [
        'password',
        'password_confirmation',
    ];

    /**
     * Report or log an exception.
     *
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public function report(Exception $exception)
    {
        parent::report($exception);
    }

    /**
     * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Exception  $exception
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }
}
```

I have confirmed the following:

- Laravel Framework 5.7.21 (`php artisan --version` output)
- It runs the appropriate code/controller based on the stack trace:

  .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php:315
  .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Factory.php:136
  .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/FoundationServiceProvider.php:53
  .../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php:108
  .../app/Http/Controllers/MyController.php:35

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post your exception handler class, i highly suggest within there is the fault

Comment: @MartinHenriksen I added the ExceptionHandler class.

Comment: I figured out why my test was crashing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having a problem with the ValidationException crashing my test because I disabled exception handling. I disabled exception handling so I can debug my tests better (ironic, I know) and I forgot that I did this.

```
class ... extends TestCase 
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        /**
         * This disables the exception handling to display the stacktrace on the console
         * the same way as it shown on the browser
         */
        parent::setUp();
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
    }
```

Removing `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();` now allows me to do assertions on the response.

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\ScheduleTest::request_schedule_with_invalid_bdate
Expected status code 200 but received 422.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Relevant links:
- https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/26013
- [laravel phpunit withexceptionhandling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46473103/laravel-phpunit-withexceptionhandling)